# How can I get the build output directory inside tests run by sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to create directories and files for some tests. My project uses sbt as the build tool, and common practice is to use `File.createTempFile` or similar APIs, but I abhor that practice. I want all files created by my tests to reside somewhere inside the output directory (`<module>/target/`), so that they'll be removed when I run `clean`, but otherwise preserved if I have need of them to figure out test failures.

The test framework is not relevant: if your solution requires a particular framework, I'll happily adopt it or figure out how it does the trick and use that.

In short, I need the answer to one of these two questions:

- How can I create a file inside the build output directory from a test run by sbt?
- How can I find out what is the build output directory for the current project from a test run by sbt?

Comment: Have you considered https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo ?

Comment: @SethTisue I have not, and that's an interesting idea. Every module needs a different key there, but I think that's doable? I haven't done much with BuildInfo except copy&paste. Go ahead an submit an answer! :)

Comment: I'm too lazy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ScalaTest, try passing [`target`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/56cf50ff2385eb8468e2724d4d0e3a9262adc335/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L114)

```
settingKey[File]("Main directory for files generated by the build.")
```

to [config map](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.1.1/org/scalatest/fixture/ConfigMapFixture.html) as `-Dkey=value`. For example, in `build.sbt` specify

```
Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument(s"-DtargetDir=${target.value}")
```

and then define test like so

```
import org.scalatest._

class ExampleSpec extends fixture.FlatSpec with fixture.ConfigMapFixture with Matchers {
  "The config map" should "contain target directory used by sbt" in { configMap =>
    configMap should contain key "targetDir"
  }
```